# What is this RF Frontend IC?

Tags: rf, bluetooth-low-energy

This is a picture of the PCB for a Tile Bluetooth tracker.

[image: https://imgur.com/RpGs3MR]

I cant find any info on this chip, and I've looked for a while for the logo. here is a closer picture. 
The logo looks like three ticks, does anyone have any ideas? It should be some sort of RF front end for the Bluetooth.

Edit: I think The Photon correctly identified the logo as that of RFMD, but I'm still having trouble finding the exact part, especially since they got acquired

From what I can tell, Pin 4 is the connection to the bluetooth IC and pin 11 is the connection to the antenna. Pins 3 and 10 are connected to GND, and beyond that its not clear.

[image]

Finally found it! It's the [RFFM6205](https://www.qorvo.com/products/p/RFFM6205), and the important code on the package is X8

Comment: Looks like an RFMD logo (now part of Qorvo).

Comment: yupp, thats definitely the one, now I just need to figure out the part number

Comment: Given time someone here will know that number or at least the manufacture. Then a search is easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse-engineering some of the traces to try and determine a feasible pinout could be useful.

Could be something like [this](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/412/ffm8204_data_sheet-780940.pdf), a Wi-Fi/BT integrated front-end module. Comparing the pinout of similar ICs to what you have should be a good indication of if you're on the right track or not.

[image: RFFM8204 Block Diagram]

Comment: Yup, it was the https://www.qorvo.com/products/p/RFFM6205